# PHP Post Webservice Issue

Tags: php

Trying to implement a post webservice in PHP so that finally it can be used in ios app for communicating to DB. Can you please identify the mistake.

Please find the code below. It is saying that "Request Method not accepted" status 0 returned

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("myhost.com","myuser","mypassword","mydb");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
// Get data
$lat= isset($_POST['lat']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['long']) : "";
$long= isset($_POST['long']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['long']) : "";
$timeStamp = isset($_POST['timeStamp']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timeStamp']) : "";
$deviceId = isset($_POST['deviceId']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['deviceId']) : "";

// Insert data into data base

$sql = "INSERT INTO `gpsReporting` (`lat`, `long`, `timeStamp`, `deviceId`)  VALUES ('$lat', '$long', '$timeStamp', '$deviceId');";
$qur = mysql_query($sql);
if($qur){
    $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Done User added!");
}else{
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error adding user!");
}
}else{
$json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
}
@mysql_close($conn);
/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: This seems to be an iOS question rather than PHP. Apparently `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is not `POST`. So check that the HTTP request in your iOS app is really using `POST`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i dont think it is ios Question.Because it should on the web by itself. May be i need to add in the text that Web Browsed showing the above error instead iOS App. Thanks for pointing out.Infact i am accessing it like this myhost.com/myfile.php.The values are already mentioned in the file.

Comment: Well that's a different story. When you enter and open an URL in your Browser you're doing a GET request - not POST. That's why it isn't working. There are several browser extensions/add-ons out there for simulating POST (and other HTTP requests) with a browser. Just google it.

Comment: thanks a lot :) actually today was my first day on PHP :( so i try to find some thing which can help. Very valid point. dont know how i missed it